# Separating SQL SELECT result-set according to WHERE condition

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

With this kind of query:

```
SELECT userID FROM Users
WHERE (condition1)
OR    (condition2)
OR    (condition3)
```

I want the result-set to somehow "differentiate" the results that met 'condition1' with those that met 'condition2' and with those that fell under 'condition3'.

For example, by somehow causing the result-set to have a second column that will contain which condition was met (1,2, or 3).

How can this be achieved?

Thank you.

Comment: This is an algorythm problem, not a sql problem. Re-think your app.

Comment: @Leandro, I don't really understand your comment, I asked how to achieve a specific goal with an SQL query, how is the "type of the problem" relevant?

Comment: @YuvalA. - Because either you're running unrelated statements (effectively) in that SQL, and/or you're not including suficient information for the application to make the distinction, _which is where it's important_.  You're applying filtering in the database that should be applied in the application layer instead.  Currently, you have to maintain the SQL and the application in sync (conditions have to match): if you provided sufficient information for the application to do it's own filtering, they become independent.

Comment: @Leandro I agree that in a more practical implementation - the information about the certain conditions - if needed by the application - should already be made available in its own column, and that the filtering-results inside a SELECT should not be the "source of information". 

Bottom line, the question was about a way to "enhance" a statistics query.

Your comment did got me thinking about something else related to this though... :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `CASE` statement for this, e.g.:

```
SELECT userID,
    case 
        when (condition1) then 1
        when (condition2) then 2
        when (condition3) then 3
    end as ConditionMet
 FROM Users
    WHERE (condition1)
    OR    (condition2)
    OR    (condition3)
```

Note: this approach will not show you if something met more than one condition. For that you probably want separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

The specific syntax for the IF clause will vary by dbms, but something like this should work:

```
select userid,
(if (condition1) THEN 1 else 0) as COndition1, 
(if (condition2) THEN 1 else 0) as COndition2, 
(if (condition3) THEN 1 else 0) as COndition3
FROM table
WHERE (condition1) or (condition2) or (condition3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same conditions specified in the where clause to add an extra column indicating which one matched. For example:

```
SELECT userID ,
case when condition1 then 'condition1'  
when condition2 then 'condition2'
else 'condition3' end as matched
FROM Users
WHERE (condition1)
OR    (condition2)
OR    (condition3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions do not overlap (i.e. are exclusive) then you can do this:

```
SELECT userID, 'condition1'
  FROM Users
  WHERE (condition1)
UNION ALL
SELECT userID, 'condition2'
  FROM Users
  WHERE (condition2)
UNION ALL
SELECT userID, 'condition3'
  FROM Users
  WHERE (condition3)
ORDER BY userID
```

However you will get duplicates if a user matches more than one condition. In certain cases this might be useful, but if you need to exclude duplicates, you could do this:

```
SELECT userID, 'condition1'
  FROM Users
  WHERE (condition1)
UNION ALL
SELECT userID, 'condition2'
  FROM Users
  WHERE (condition2) AND NOT (condition1)
UNION ALL
SELECT userID, 'condition3'
  FROM Users
  WHERE (condition3) AND NOT (condition2) AND NOT (condition1)
ORDER BY userID
```